# ASP.NET MVC 3 with EF not recognizing the many to many join table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

In my database I have a User table and then another table with something like roles. There is a many to many join table between them. When someone is making a new user they have to be able to select the role they want for the user. However EF is not letting me associate my user with this other table. I had a dropdown list, but when the role was selected an invalid enrty error came up saying the PKID was not the correct input. 
I must be missing something in how EF works, or at least how it links to MVC 3

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you have a many to many relationship you need a separate table to hold the two foreign keys.

So you might have:

```
User
------
ID
Name


Role
------
ID
Name


UserRoles
------
ID
UserID
RoleID
```

Why do you need a many to many relationship here? If I were you I'd create something like

```
User
------
ID
Name
IDRoleType


Role
------
ID
RoleType
```

That way a user can have a role, and in your code you can do something like:

```
public IQueryable FindUsers()
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
    return db.Users.Where(u => u.IDRoleType == 0);
}
```

Or

```
public IQueryable FindUsers()
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
    return db.Users.Where(u => u.Role.RoleType == "Admin");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, however the table needs a many to many since the user will have multiple roles